# React-native show Image uri empty screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just got an issue to load this image from uri like this

`<Image style={{ width: '100%' }} source={{uri:'http://192.168.43.225:8887/imgUpload/1739998147-71.jpg'}}/>`

The image is not showing. But when I using native-base Thumbnail it work well, but it not what I want

`<Thumbnail style={{ width: '100%' }} source={{uri:'http://192.168.43.225:8887/imgUpload/1739998147-71.jpg'}}/>`

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the height and width, either in the `source` attribute or in the `style`.

E.g. 1

```
<Image source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_small.png', width: 38, height: 38}} />
```

E.g. 2

```
<Image style={{height: 38, width: 38}} source={{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/img/logo_small.png'}} />
```

Comment: Thank's, by adding height to Image fixed the problem